# Migrate UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration to UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration without losing row spacing, padding, background color

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I am using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration` and `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
class ChecklistCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var rowView: UIView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        initRowView()
    }

    private func initRowView() {
        rowView.layer.cornerRadius = 22
        rowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        rowView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private func layoutConfig() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {        
        let configuration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        configuration.scrollDirection = .vertical
        
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout (sectionProvider: { [weak self] (sectionNumber, env) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            guard let self = self else { return nil }
            
            let heightDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension =
                .estimated(CGFloat(44))
            
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                heightDimension: heightDimension
            )
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                heightDimension: heightDimension
            )
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            
            section.interGroupSpacing = 4

            section.contentInsets = .init(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8)
            return section
        }, configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

Here's is my outcome

### Using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration

[image]

The collection view rows have

1. Rounded corner, and semi-transparent background
2. Spacing and padding

Now, I would love to migrate to `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration`, because I would like to have a swipe to delete feature.

I have tried.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private func layoutConfig() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {        
        var listConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
        
        listConfig.showsSeparators = false
        
        listConfig.trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider = { indexPath -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? in

            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(
                actions: [
                    UIContextualAction(
                        style: .destructive,
                        title: "Delete",
                        handler: { [weak self] (_, _, completion) in
                            completion(true)
                        })
                ]
            )
        }
        
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: listConfig)
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting.

### Using UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration

[image]

Note,

1. Rounded corner, and semi-transparent background no longer seen. It seems that the background setup in `UICollectionViewCell` is no longer being adhered.
2. Spacing and padding no longer seen.

Do you have any idea, how I can fix such?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` in a `.plain` appearance, you are basically replicating a standard `UITableView`. Such a layout does not have configuration for spacing and padding. You need to add that in your cell's content.

Start by setting the `backgroundColor` of `listConfig` to match the desired collection view background color. Update your `layoutConfig` function by adding:

```
listConfig.backgroundColor = UIColor(...) // your light orange color
```

This will now make your cell content visible. More specifically, it will make the transparent white background of `rowView` and its rounded corners visible again.

At this point you may need to modify the constraints on the `rowView` property of your cell so it appears inset from the cell's `contentView`. This will give the appearance of padding between the cells even though there will not be any actual spacing between each cell.

---

Here is a code-only implementation loosely based on your own code that demonstrates what you are asking for. This makes use of your exact `layoutConfig` except for the addition of setting the background color as I mentioned in my answer above. Obviously you can change the constraints of the collection view and the cell's content to match your actual needs.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil

    private func layoutConfig() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        var listConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
        listConfig.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250.0/255, green: 128.0/255, blue: 114.0/255, alpha: 1)

        listConfig.showsSeparators = false

        listConfig.trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider = { indexPath -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? in

            return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(
                actions: [
                    UIContextualAction(
                        style: .destructive,
                        title: "Delete",
                        handler: { [weak self] (_, _, completion) in
                            completion(true)
                        })
                ]
            )
        }

        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: listConfig)
    }

    private func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layoutConfig())
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        configureHierarchy()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let cfg = CellConfiguration(title: "Item \(indexPath.item)")
        cell.contentConfiguration = cfg

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

class CellContentView : UIView, UIContentView {
    var configuration: UIContentConfiguration {
        didSet {
            configure(configuration: configuration)
        }
    }

    private var capsule: UIView = UIView()
    private var nameLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    init(_ configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        capsule.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        capsule.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(capsule)

        nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        nameLabel.textColor = .label
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(nameLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            capsule.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5),
            capsule.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            capsule.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            capsule.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 40),
            nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        guard let configuration = configuration as? CellConfiguration else { return }

        nameLabel.text = configuration.title
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        capsule.layer.cornerRadius = (bounds.height - 10) / 2
    }
}

struct CellConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
    var title: String

    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        return CellContentView(self)
    }
    
    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> Self {
        return self
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: No. It just simply doesn't work. How do you achieve round corner, spacing, semi-transparent row background with such a `listConfig.backgroundColor`?

Comment: Your existing ChecklistCell already provides the rounded corner and semi-transparent row background of each cell. My answer explains how fix your use of `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` when combined with your existing custom cell.

Comment: I've added full code to my answer. Please have a look.